# Copy/multiply cell contents based on number in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google, copy-paste

I have a list of items, Col. B & numbers in Col. A.
I want to multiply/copy the text in cell B based on the number in their relative cell A. I.e. multiply **'B'** by the number of times in ***'A'***

Here's the sample spreadsheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jbgugr93t6CYY08Bi83SH3pWJIH8B1ukfCKiPwtt4M/edit?usp=sharing

I've also shown in Col. D in red, what I envision as my result would look like. Right now I do this manually, copy the contents the relevant number of times.

Is there a way to do this faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(flatten(IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT(B1:B&"@",A1:A),"@")))),"where Col1<>'' ")
```

[image]

How the (undocumented) `flatten` function work.
When we use `flatten` on an array of cells, it **transposes the array row by row into a single column**.

Please notice the **difference between `flatten` and `TRANSPOSE`**

```
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| array of cells  | =flatten(A1:C2) |  =TRANSPOSE(A1:C2)  |
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
|   1  |  2  |  3 |        1        |     1    |     4    |
|   4  |  5  |  6 |        2        |     2    |     5    |
|      |     |    |        3        |     3    |     6    |
|      |     |    |        4        |          |          |
|      |     |    |        5        |          |          |
|      |     |    |        6        |          |          |
+------+-----+----+-----------------+----------+----------+
```

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)

Comment: Hey @marikamitsos, thank you again for your quick response! It works like magic! :) :)

Comment: Season's greetings. Glad I worked for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",REPT(ROW(A:A)&"@",A:A)),"@",0,1)),{ROW(A:A),B:B},2,FALSE))`

**How It Works**

`=ArrayFormula(...)` signifies that the formula will process an entire range and not just one cell.

Now, working from the inside out...

`REPT(ROW(A:A)&"@",A:A)` will add the `@` symbol onto the end of each row number and then repeat that string however many times is listed in A:A. For instance, if row 1 Column A indicates to repeat 1x, the string for that row will be `1@`. If row 2 Column A indicates it is to repeat 2x, the sting for that row will be `2@2@`.

`JOIN("",...)`

All of those strings will be joined into one long string (e.g., `1@2@2@3@3@3@`...)

`SPLIT(...,"@",0,1)`

That long string will be split apart at the `@` symbol into a long virtual *row* of individual numbers, e.g.:

1 2 2 3 3 3...

`TRANSPOSE(...)`

That long virtual *row* of individual numbers will be transposed into a *column* of the same numbers, e.g.:

1

2

2

3

3

3

etc.

`VLOOKUP(...,{ROW(A:A),B:B},2,FALSE))`

Each of those individual numbers in the column will be looked up within a virtual array composed of all row numbers in column one and all B:B text in column two. When each exact match is found (signified by `FALSE`), the Column `2` data will be returned.

Comment: Hey Erik, thank you for your answer too. It works like magic :D. & best of all you've broken down the steps. It helps understand this really well.

Comment: Happy to have helped broaden your Sheets knowledge, Genny. If everyone helps someone just a little, in whatever ways we can, the world can't help but be a better place.